# How to plot density for repeated k-fold cross validation?

Tags: regression, r-squared, density-estimation, discrete-distributions

Long story short, I conducted regression using repeated k-fold cross validation. While messing around I decided to plot the density of the R-squared distribution for the resampling. Obviously there are no true negative R-squared values in the distribution, but the tail end crosses over into the negative.

1) Is this something I should be worried about? I'm inclined to think that the model is a bit iffy if this happens?

2) Can R-squared be considered a discrete distribution here and this is just a by-product of using a kernel density estimate on a discrete distribution?

3) What would be an appropriate way to plot such a distribution?

[image]

Will I get laughed at if I plot it like below? This graph is actually semi-informative (to me at least)

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the last plot. Why aren’t your RMSE and $R^2$ perfectly (negatively) Spearman correlated?

Comment: actually.. if it is really resampling, your r square is quite crazy, you can actually go from 0 to 0.4 ??

Comment: It's PLS regression, but looking at the resampling distribution, I'm not 100% sure I should trust any model, as it looks super unstable. It's also independently "crazy" for both males and females

Comment: yeah you can also plot your density using plot(density(.., from=0,to=0.6)) , this will ensure it doesn't go into -ve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re adding together a bunch of Gaussian densities. The expectation is that some of the density in your KDE will be in impossible regions, unless all real numbers are theoretically possible like they are in a Gaussian distribution.

1) This may be an issue if you’re trying to calculate the true density, but for visualizing the shape and spread of some observations, I do not consider this a big deal.

2) This isn’t an issue of discrete vs continuous. Sampling from a  continuous uniform distribution will result in a KDE that leaks into areas not allowed by the original distribution.

3) I think you’re fine to use the KDE you’re using. An alternative to the KDE is to use a histogram.